# How does Imagick::averageImages work?

Tags: php, imagick

I've been trying to figure out how `Imagick::averageImages ( void )` works, but so far I was unsuccesful. According to the php manual: "This function is currently not documented; only its argument list is available.". All other searches online also did not turn up any useful results. I would expect such a function to take an array of Imagick objects and return a new object containing the average. However this function takes 0 arguments. Could anyone perhaps provide an example on how this function is supposed to be used? Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

from: http://www.rubblewebs.co.uk/imagick/functions/functions.php

```
<?php 
$im = new Imagick();
$im->readImage('annotateImage.jpg');
$im->readImage('addNoiseImage.jpg');
$im->readImage('adaptiveBlurImage.jpg');
$im->resetIterator();
$average = $im->averageImages();
$average->writeImage('averageImages.jpg'); 
$average->destroy();
 ?>
```

Answer (score 0):

Actually I just realized this is pretty trivial. An Imagick object can have contain multiple images.

```
$img = new Imagick();
$img->addImage($img1);
$img->addImage($img2);
$img->addImage($img3);
$img->averageImages();
```